# how to know from which node the file / block was retrieved when querying https://ipfs.io/ipfs/

Tags: ipfs

When a file is queried from a public gateway using the hash, the gateway queries the peer nodes and gives back the content as http response.

For example,

- a file added locally generated a hash QmXjFR1MiAMYprPjwLQwXXonYK52FihQVEL6a2dh3uhUey, which
- when used as https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXjFR1MiAMYprPjwLQwXXonYK52FihQVEL6a2dh3uhUey the gateway queries my local node (which has the file) and gives back that retrieved content in the browser.

The question is:

- is there any way, say response header or some other way, of knowing from **which peer / remote machine** the gateway retrieved the content ? (in the above example my machine's **peer-id**)

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is **no** (as of `v0.4.20`). The process IPFS goes through when retrieving a block is:

1. Do the following at the same time:

   1. Notify all current peers that you want the block (e.g. `QmXjFR1...`)
   2. Ask the network to find providers of the block you want (e.g. `QmXjFR1...`)
2. If a peer has the block, it will send it over and you will disregard any providers that are found.
3. If no peer has the block and a provider is found, then the provider is added as a peer and is notified that you want the block (e.g. `QmXjFR1...`), at which point the peer starts sending the block over.

In theory, if you run the IPFS node you could maybe do things to determine what peer a block is coming from. But the gateway doesn't offer that information through its interface AFAIK.

Anyway, I don't see anything in the response headers. Here's an example from hitting the gateway API:

```
λ curl -v https://gateway.ipfs.io/api/v0/cat/QmT78zSuBmuS4z925WZfrqQ1qHaJ56DQaTfyMUF7F8ff5o
*   Trying 2602:fea2:2::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to gateway.ipfs.io (2602:fea2:2::1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=ipfs.io
*  start date: May  7 21:37:01 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Aug  5 21:37:01 2019 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "gateway.ipfs.io" matched cert's "*.ipfs.io"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x7ff002806600)
> GET /api/v0/cat/QmT78zSuBmuS4z925WZfrqQ1qHaJ56DQaTfyMUF7F8ff5o HTTP/2
> Host: gateway.ipfs.io
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
< HTTP/2 200
< server: nginx
< date: Wed, 22 May 2019 04:32:43 GMT
< content-type: text/plain
< vary: Accept-Encoding
< trailer: X-Stream-Error
< vary: Origin
< x-content-length: 12
< x-stream-output: 1
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
< access-control-allow-headers: X-Requested-With, Range, Content-Range, X-Chunked-Output, X-Stream-Output
< access-control-expose-headers: Content-Range, X-Chunked-Output, X-Stream-Output
< x-ipfs-pop: gateway-bank2-sjc1
< strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
<
hello world
* Connection #0 to host gateway.ipfs.io left intact
```

Comment: Here is the follow-up of the conversation: https://discuss.ipfs.io/t/is-there-a-way-to-know-the-peerid-from-the-gateway-response/5439/4